# Can someone help me convert this sqlite query to a postgres query?

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, syncfusion

```
SELECT substr(strftime('%Y', date),3,2) AS month, 0 AS zero FROM listvalue
```

I have this query in SQLite, when I import it into Postgres I'm having problem translating the `substr(strftime('%Y', date),3,2)` part.

Comment: So what does this `strftime()` function do? Are you looking for `to_char(date, 'yyyy')`? (Btw: `date` is a horrible name for a column)

Comment: Why are you calling the last two digits of the *year* by the name *month*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`substr(strftime('%Y', date),3,2)` extracts the last 2 digits of the year part of the column `date`, but in your code you alias it `as month`!
if you want to do the same in Postgresql you can use `extract()` to get the year, typecast it to `varchar` and use `substr()` to get the last 2 chars:

```
substr(extract(year from date)::varchar, 3, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can translate the expression with [`TO_CHAR`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-formatting.html) function to PostgreSQL:

```
SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(date, 'YYYY'), 3, 2)
```

Note: The format `%Y` will return the year of the date and not the month as your query suggests.

The SQLite query will return the last to digits of year of the date. You can omit the `SUBSTR` in PostgreSQL call by using the apropriate format:

```
TO_CHAR(date, 'YY')
```

Comment: I've tried this but its bringing years as YY instead of YYY "999" worked better

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Do you want the three last digits of the year?

Answer (score -1):

We suspect that you want to extract the last two digits of the year value from the date column. The strftime() function won’t work in Postgres server. So, suggest you to use either one of the below queries to achieve your requirement,

```
SELECT substring(date_part('year', date)::varchar, 3, 2) AS year, 0 AS zero FROM listvalue;  

SELCT to_char(shipped_date, 'YY'), 0 AS zero from listvalue;
```

Thanks, 
Renuka N.